# Failed to extract variables from JSON reponse in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I get response in `JSON` format in JMeter.

```
{"data1":{"file":"myfile","contentType":"text/xml"},"data2":{"file":"myfile","contentType":"text/xml"}}
```

I use `jp@gc JSON Path Extractor` plugin to get value of `file` fields. One instance for each.

Expression 1: `$.data1.file`

Expression 2: `$.data2.file`

I use `Debug Sampler` to check value of destination variables. None of these has value, when I check it there, but first one has value, when I use `vars.get("destvar1")` in a `JSR223 Sampler`. I tried also built-in JSON Post Processor, but produces same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) **as a child** of the request which returns the above JSON. JSON Extractor obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) therefore you need to ensure that it is applied only to the "interesting" sampler
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Name of created variables: `destvar1;destvar2`
   - JSON Path expressions: `$.data1.file;$.data2.file`
   - Default values: `notfound;notfound`

     [image]
3. That's it, you should see the values using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination

   [image]